# MongoDB Many to Many Two ways of Implementation: Reference or Embed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many, mongoose-schema

I am using MongoDB (and mongoose) for storing my data about: `Clubs` & `Tracks`.

As you might guess: 

`Club` has many `Track`-s. 

`Track` might be in many `Club`-s.


I know two ways to save them into DB. **First** being:

`Club {
   name: String,
   tracks: [Track] // Track Schema be defined similarly above it. But! it won't have a separate table, correct?
}`

Whereas, **second** would be:
`Club {
   name: String,
   tracks: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Track' }] // This means Track will have a separate table, correct?
}`

Now, the following requests(queries) to database will have, more or less, equal frequency. And will look something like this:
1. get tracks by club_id
2. search tracks by name
3. search clubs by track, etc

I believe it won't be a healthy approach to have same tracks in different places over and over again (which is likely to happen in case of the first approach).
I think, first approach would be right way if I had blog and comments.

What way do you suggest and why?

Comment: To be many to many, the second option should be  tracks: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Track' }]  (an array of track refs). The first case is of embedding which is inappropriate because, as you said, it will replicate tracks across multiple clubs. The second approach is great so far as the number of tracks per club are limited. Otherwise, you might want to consider an associative collection containing ids of both track and club (sql style).

Comment: @TalhaAwan `tracks` was a mistake. Corrected.
As for tracks per club - What do you think of an average number of 500? small enough for the existing strategy or should I go for associative sql style?

Comment: In that case you should consider the update frequency of the club document, especially in relation to `tracks` array. If too many clients are updating the array simultaneously, you may come across race condition and stale data. This is perhaps more important than the size of the array. Associative docs don't pose this issue at all, as you don't need to update the club while doing whatever with the track (and vice versa). But for few and far between updates from a small number of users/clients the array approach, even with a few thousand references, should be ok in my opinion.